# Sending large data (like a file) over TCP in C++ winsock

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, tcp, transfer

I am trying to create a program in C++ using TCP for file transfer, however I have come across a problem which is difficult to desrcibe:

This is the recieve thread in the server, what it does is recv() on a loop and handle the packets recieved from that client.

the function() is a log function, basically, the first byte in the packet is supposed to be the message ID. 
100 stands for beginning a file transfer
101 stands for transferring the data chunks
102 stands for finishing the transfer

200 and 201 are responses that I thought can help.
Apparently, if on the client I wait for a response from the server each time I send a data chunk, the file transfer works like magic BUT it works really slow because of the pings between computers.

What I am trying to do is make the client send the data to the server without having to wait for the server response each time it sends data.

```
void RecvThread(Object ^lpv)
{
//  function("Hello! %s", ManagedStringToChar( (String^)lpv ) );
//  function("Socket ID : %d!", (System::UInt32)lpv);
    char recvbuf[4096*10];
    int nrecvret;
    SOCKET clientsocket = (SOCKET)lpv;
    do {

        nrecvret = recv(clientsocket, recvbuf, 4096*10, 0);
        if (nrecvret > 0) {
//          function("Bytes received: %d\n", nrecvret);
            BYTE msgID = recvbuf[0];
            switch (msgID)
            {
                case 100:
                {
                    nfilecount++;
                    DWORD dwFileSize = *(DWORD*)(recvbuf + 1);
                    function("File size: %d.\n", dwFileSize);
                    fileList[nfilecount].nSize = dwFileSize;
                    fileList[nfilecount].pData = (unsigned char*)malloc(dwFileSize);
                    break;
                }
                case 101:
                {

                    BYTE *pData = (BYTE*)recvbuf;
                    pData++;
                    unsigned int nSection = *(DWORD*)(pData);
                    pData += 4;
                    unsigned int nLength = *(DWORD*)(pData);
                    pData += 4;

                    function("Recieved msg id item data! Section %d, length %d\n", nSection , nLength);
                    for (int i = 0; i < nLength; i++)
                        fileList[nfilecount].pData[nSection+i] = pData[i];
                    if (nSection + nLength != fileList[nfilecount].nSize)
                    {
                        BYTE* pSendPacketOrg = (BYTE*)malloc(0x5);
                        BYTE* pSend = pSendPacketOrg;
                        pSend[0] = 200;
                        pSend++;
                        *(DWORD*)pSend = nSection + nLength;
                        function("%d : %d. Requesting %d...", nSection, nLength, nSection + nLength);
                        send(clientsocket, (char*)pSendPacketOrg, 5, 0);
                    }
                    if (nSection + nLength == fileList[nfilecount].nSize)
                    {
                        function("Recieved all sections!");
                        BYTE pSend = 201;
                        send(clientsocket, (char*)&pSend, 1, 0);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 102:
                {
                    function("finished recieving file!\n");
                    FILE* file = fopen("FileRecieved.dat", "wb");
                    if (file)
                    {
                        int nWritten = 0;
                        while (nWritten < fileList[nfilecount].nSize)
                        {
                            int nToWrite = 1024 * 1024;
                            int Remaining = fileList[nfilecount].nSize - nWritten;
                            if (Remaining <= nToWrite)
                                nToWrite = Remaining;
                            int nBytesWritten = fwrite(fileList[nfilecount].pData + nWritten, 1, nToWrite, file);
                            nWritten += nBytesWritten;
                        }
                    }
                    fclose(file);
                    break;
                }
                case 't':
                {
                    // Echo the buffer back to the sender
                    function("Recieved handshake!\n");
                    int nsendret = send(clientsocket, recvbuf, nrecvret, 0);
                    if (nsendret == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                        function("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                        //              closesocket(clientsocket);
                        //              WSACleanup();
                        break;
                    }
//                  function("Bytes sent: %d\n", nsendret);
                    break;
                }
                default:
                {
                    function("Unknown msgID: %d, size: %d\n", msgID, nrecvret);
                    function("Last error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                    break;
                }   
            }


        }
        else if (nrecvret < 0)
        {
            if (errno == EAGAIN)
            {
                function("recv() timed out.\n");
            }
            else
            {
                function("recv() failed due to errno = %d\n", errno);
//              exit(1);
            }
        }
        else if (nrecvret == 0)
            function("Connection closing...\n");
        else if (WSAGetLastError() == 10053)
        {
            function("An established connection was aborted by the software in your host computer, possibly due to a data transmission time-out or protocol error.\n");
            break;
        }
        else  {
            function("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }

    } while (nrecvret > 0);

    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    function("Shutting down and closing socket %d...\n", clientsocket);
    nrecvret = shutdown(clientsocket, SD_SEND);
    if (nrecvret == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        function("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(clientsocket);
//      WSACleanup();
        return;
    }
}
```

This part of code is from the client.
The client connects, says hi, and sends data I have allocated (just for tests for now) to the server.
I have added some commentary to help understand the code.

```
int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned char* pData; // "file" data
    unsigned int nSize = 1023928; // "file" size, 
    pData = (unsigned char*)malloc(nSize); // for now these are allocated instead of reading a file
    for (int i = 0; i < nSize; i++)
        pData[i] = 0xD2; // the data for the file would be 0xD2 throughout the whole file

    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
        hints;
    char *sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char *szServerIP = "109.xx.xxx.xx"; // server IP, censored
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN]; // default buflen is 512
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(szServerIP, "6005", &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    int count = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        count++;
        printf("[%d] Connecting... \n", count);
        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype,
            result->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Connected to the server on port 6005! Now sending data...");

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0); // says hi
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    // Wait for the server to say hi back
    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
        {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            break;
        }

        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while (iResult > 0);

    Sleep(2000); // wait 2 seconds and then send our data


    BYTE *pSizePacketOrg = (BYTE*)malloc(5);// packet 100 sends data size
    BYTE *pSizePacket = pSizePacketOrg;//
    pSizePacket[0] = 100;//
    pSizePacket++;//
    *(DWORD*)pSizePacket = 1023928;//

    printf("Sending 100\n");
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)pSizePacketOrg, 5, 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send 100 with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    free(pSizePacketOrg);
    unsigned int nWritten = 0;
    printf("Sending 101\n"); // packet 101 sends the data, in chunks
    while (nWritten < nSize)
    {
        unsigned int nToWrite = 1024;
        printf("nToWrite %d\n", nToWrite);
        unsigned int Remaining = nSize - nWritten;
        printf("nRemaining %d\n", nToWrite);
        if (Remaining <= nToWrite)
        {
            nToWrite = Remaining;
            printf("Remaining smaller or equal to write. Writing %d.\n", nToWrite);
        }
        BYTE *pSendPacketOrg = (BYTE*)malloc(nToWrite + 1 + 4 + 4);
        BYTE* pSendPacket = pSendPacketOrg;
        pSendPacket[0] = 101;
        pSendPacket++;
        *(DWORD*)pSendPacket = nWritten;
        pSendPacket += 4;
        *(DWORD*)pSendPacket = nToWrite;
        pSendPacket += 4;
        memcpy(pSendPacket, (pData + nWritten), nToWrite);
    //  Sleep(100);
//      Sleep(20);
        int nBytesWritten = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)pSendPacketOrg, nToWrite + 9, 0);
        if (nBytesWritten == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("send 101 : %d:%d with error: %d\n", nWritten, nToWrite, WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        free(pSendPacketOrg);
        printf("written %d bytes.\n", nBytesWritten);
        nWritten += nBytesWritten-9; // -9 because of the information before the data

        if (nWritten == nSize) // if finished sending everything, wait for a response from the server
        {
            int nResponse = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
            if (nResponse == 1)
            {
                if (((BYTE*)recvbuf)[0] == 201) // server notified finished recieving
                {
                    printf("Server finished recieving! send end file...");
                    break;
                }
            }
            //int nResponse = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
            //if (nResponse == 5)
            //{
            //  if ( ((BYTE*)recvbuf)[0] == 200)
            //  {
            //      printf("Server is requesting %d!", *(DWORD*)(recvbuf + 1));
            //  }
            //}
        }

//      Sleep(50);
    }

    printf("Sending 102\n"); // confirming the end of the transmission
    BYTE pEndPacket = 102;
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, (char*)(&pEndPacket), 1, 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send 102 with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    Sleep(1000);
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    Sleep(10000);

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

In my log file, when I run the client and server locally from my computer it works almost perfectly:

```
[LOG] Recieved handshake!
[LOG] File size: 1023928.
[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 0, length 36864
[LOG] 0 : 36864. Requesting 36864...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 36864, length 36864
[LOG] 36864 : 36864. Requesting 73728...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 73728, length 36864
[LOG] 73728 : 36864. Requesting 110592...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 110592, length 36864
[LOG] 110592 : 36864. Requesting 147456...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 147456, length 36864
[LOG] 147456 : 36864. Requesting 184320...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 184320, length 36864
[LOG] 184320 : 36864. Requesting 221184...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 221184, length 36864
[LOG] 221184 : 36864. Requesting 258048...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 258048, length 36864
[LOG] 258048 : 36864. Requesting 294912...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 294912, length 36864
[LOG] 294912 : 36864. Requesting 331776...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 331776, length 36864
[LOG] 331776 : 36864. Requesting 368640...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 368640, length 36864
[LOG] 368640 : 36864. Requesting 405504...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 405504, length 36864
[LOG] 405504 : 36864. Requesting 442368...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 442368, length 36864
[LOG] 442368 : 36864. Requesting 479232...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 479232, length 36864
[LOG] 479232 : 36864. Requesting 516096...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 516096, length 36864
[LOG] 516096 : 36864. Requesting 552960...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 552960, length 36864
[LOG] 552960 : 36864. Requesting 589824...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 589824, length 36864
[LOG] 589824 : 36864. Requesting 626688...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 626688, length 36864
[LOG] 626688 : 36864. Requesting 663552...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 663552, length 36864
[LOG] 663552 : 36864. Requesting 700416...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 700416, length 36864
[LOG] 700416 : 36864. Requesting 737280...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 737280, length 36864
[LOG] 737280 : 36864. Requesting 774144...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 774144, length 36864
[LOG] 774144 : 36864. Requesting 811008...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 811008, length 36864
[LOG] 811008 : 36864. Requesting 847872...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 847872, length 36864
[LOG] 847872 : 36864. Requesting 884736...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 884736, length 36864
[LOG] 884736 : 36864. Requesting 921600...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 921600, length 36864
[LOG] 921600 : 36864. Requesting 958464...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 958464, length 36864
[LOG] 958464 : 36864. Requesting 995328...[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 995328, length 28600
[LOG] Recieved all sections![LOG] finished recieving file!
```

However... When I am running the client from a remote PC, this is how the server log looks like:

```
[LOG] Recieved handshake!
[LOG] File size: 1023928.
[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 0, length 36864
[LOG] 0 : 36864. Requesting 36864...[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 36720
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 36720
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 35972
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Recieved msg id item data! Section 147456, length 36864
[LOG] 147456 : 36864. Requesting 184320...[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 40960
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 1967
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 6800
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 593
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 35980
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 36720
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 0, size: 37214
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 36582
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 38080
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 36720
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 36506
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 36410
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 36720
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 38080
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 36720
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 4080
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 32640
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 36720
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 36720
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 1360
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 35123
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 36720
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 36720
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 37899
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 36234
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 1360
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 35360
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 36720
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Unknown msgID: 210, size: 28515
[LOG] Last error: 183
[LOG] Connection closing...
[LOG] Shutting down and closing socket 680...
```

I recieve packets the client did not send, all different in size, I am assuming that they are the file data because the first byte in the packet is 210 ( dec for 0xD2, which I set as the "file" data)
But why are the packets being recieved like that?

I was told there should be some delay, maybe something that has to do with blocking or nonblocking functions, I am not an expert in networking...

Take in mind that waiting for a server response every time the client sends a packet is the goal I wish to avoid, because I want to ensure maximum transmission speed, and the ping between the computers decreases the rate in which the data is being transferred. 
Should I add a socket option to my code? Is there something I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, Johnny!

Comment: TCP already handles sending an ACK for received packets. Why be redundant? Just stream the entire file to the server without all the additional overhead and let the protocol stack handle it.

Comment: What @CaptainObvlious says - you're making it much harder than it needs to be:(

Comment: Thanks guys! All I did is just send the file and stop waiting for it when the size recieved reaches the file size!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you dont't have to manually do ACKs as TCP has already done for you.

If you must manually do ACK for some reason, then what you need to do to is windowing, which is to allow certain number of packets unACKed to maxly utilize the network's capacity. (But determining the window size is a hard task, and is still already done by TCP)